# How to set the row_number while UNNEST in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, row-number, unnest

Example:
There is a column "fruits" with the value: "apple, orange".

How to get two columns???

```
fruit  row_number
apple  1 
orange  2
```

I have tried
UNNEST(SPLIT(fruits)) as fruit together with
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fruit).
But sometimes it gives the result:

```
fruit  row_number
apple  2
orange  1
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to do a pivot?

Comment: I want one value "apple, orange" to be split into two values "apple" and "orange". But the main problem is to set the exact row_number for values.

Comment: Is your question how do you get the ordering of the row_number to be consistent with the original order of the array?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want "apple" to have row_number = 1 but not 2.

Comment: `select fruit, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by fruit) as rownumber 
from unnest(["apple","banana","orange"]) fruit`

Comment: "order by fruit" will not work because I need the ordering by the position in the original value.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

> UNNEST(SPLIT(fruits)) as fruit WITH OFFSET as offset